# Can you change axis labels for each specific graph in facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, facet-wrap

So I need to change the specific x-axis labels in each graph, but I cannot how to do this. I have limited programming knowledge, and my solutions are not working.

Here is the graph:
[Graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ1SP.png)

However, I need the graph for 5505 to say "Week x FU" instead of "Month x FU".

Here is the working code that produced the above graph:

```
   Moderate <- ggplot(data=CTALdataModerate, aes(x=treatmentHour, y=CTAL_T, group=1)) + geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~SSID, nrow = 2, scales = "free_x", shrink = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,10), breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 1)) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"),
                     labels = c("Baseline", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30",
                                "35", "Post", "Month 1 FU", "Month 2 FU")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=65,hjust=1)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 11, family = "A")) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines")) +
  labs(x = ".", y = ".") +
  ggtitle(".") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 11)) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,.1,0,.1), "in"))

Moderate
```

And here is the code that I tried to do, but it is erroring out. I've tried multiple things, but I really don't know how to tackle this problem:

```
i <- "S_5502"
j <- "S_5505"

#Plot the response proportions
Moderate <- ggplot(data=CTALdataModerate, aes(x=treatmentHour, y=CTAL_T, group=1)) + geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~SSID, nrow = 2, scales = "free_x", shrink = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(3,10), breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 1)) +
  for (i in CTALdataModerate$SSID){scale_x_discrete(limits = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"),
    labels = c("Baseline", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30",
                              "35", "Post", "Month 1 FU", "Month 2 FU"))} +
  for (j in CTALdataModerate$SSID){scale_x_discrete(limits = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"),
    labels = c("Baseline", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30",
                              "35", "Post", "Week 1 FU", "Week 2 FU"))} +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=65,hjust=1)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 11, family = "A")) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines")) +
  labs(x = ".", y = ".") +
  ggtitle(".") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 11)) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,.1,0,.1), "in"))

#View plot
Moderate
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your picture doesn't contain "Week 2 FU". Are you sure you've specified the correct labels?

Comment: That is the issue. I need the top graph to say "Month 2 FU" and the bottom graph to say "Week 2 FU", but I cannot figure out how to append the x-axis labels for each graph independently.

Comment: The best solution would be modifying your data before you put it in. update values with ifelse statements and set the order using factors.

Comment: @DanielV I looked into trying to order it using factors, but I could not figure it out on my own. Unfortunately, I do not have a resource to ask and I'm trying to figure it out on my own. Do you have a reference/guide for doing what you proposed? If so, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: If you do x <- factor(c("a", "b", "c"), levels = c("a", "c", "b")) then plotting it will do it as "a", "c", "b" rather than "a", "b", "c"

Comment: Can you add data for your example using `dput`. `dput(CTALdataModerate)` ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, let me first illustrate your problem with the data that I made up. By the way, if you had provided the example data, you could have received an answer much quicker.

### The problem

```
library(ggplot2)
CTALdataModerate <- data.frame(treatmentHour = rep(c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"), 2), 
                              CTAL_T = runif(22, min= 1, max = 10), 
                              group = 1, 
                              SSID = rep(c("S_5502", "S_5505"), each=11)) 
Moderate <- ggplot(data=CTALdataModerate, aes(x=treatmentHour, y=CTAL_T, group=1)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~SSID, nrow = 2, scales = "free_x", shrink = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,10), breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"),
                   labels = c("Baseline", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30",
                              "35", "Post", "Month 1 FU", "Month 2 FU")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=65,hjust=1)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 11, family = "A")) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines")) +
  labs(x = ".", y = ".") +
  ggtitle(".") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 11)) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,.1,0,.1), "in"))
Moderate
```

[image]

The problem is to assign different labels to the same vales: "10" and "11".

### Solution

All you need to do is to change your data to make them different. In the following code, I added "12" and "13", and labeled them accordingly.

```
CTALdataModerate <- data.frame(
  treatmentHour = factor(c(1:11, 1:9, 12, 13), 
                         levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"), 
                         labels = c("Baseline", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30",
                                    "35", "Post", "Month 1 FU", "Month 2 FU", "Week 1 FU", "Week 2 FU")), 
  CTAL_T = runif(22, min= 1, max = 10), 
  group = 1, 
  SSID = rep(c("S_5502", "S_5505"), each=11))
```

Then, copied your code here, I only removed the  `scale_x_discrete` line:

```
Moderate <- ggplot(data=CTALdataModerate, aes(x=treatmentHour, y=CTAL_T, group=1)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~SSID, nrow = 2, scales = "free_x", shrink = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,10), breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=65,hjust=1)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 11, family = "A")) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines")) +
  labs(x = ".", y = ".") +
  ggtitle(".") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 11)) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,.1,0,.1), "in"))
Moderate
```

Now the graph has new labels:

[image]